# Kindly suggest me how to create depend Textboxes in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have numeric `textbox1`, numeric `textbox2` and numeric `textbox3`, where `textbox3` should show the value that is the multiple of `textbox1` and `textbox2`. The `textbox3` should change dynamically when the values in the other two change. Thanks.

Comment: Nobody will do it for You. Show us code which YOu wrote and somebody can help You with Your problem.

Hint: To resolve Your problem You can use JavaScript and onChange event.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to either use javascript and do it client side, ajax and do it server side, or set the textboxes to postback automatically on change.

I'd recommend using jquery:

```
$('#textbox1, #textbox2').change(function() {
    $('#textbox3').val(parseFloat($('#textbox1').val()) * parseFloat($('#textbox2').val()));
});
```

Where #textbox1, #textbox2 and #textbox3 are the ID's of the three textboxes. (You may need to use <%= TextBox1.ClientId %> if you're using ASP.NET as the ID's are generated dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function calculate()
{
    if((document.getElementById("TextBox1").value != "") && (document.getElementById("TextBox2").value != ""))
    {
        document.getElementById("TextBox3").value = document.getElementById("TextBox1").value * document.getElementById("TextBox2").value;
    }
}
</script>

  <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1" onblur="calculate();"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox2" onblur="calculate();"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox3"></asp:TextBox>
```